# Convergence of series with two variables

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation

In an electronics application I've found this summation:
$$
 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{m - n+1} \cdot \beta^n  \cdot \alpha^m
$$
Both $|\alpha|$ and $|\beta|$ are <1 .
Does this summation converge to a value which is computable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rearrange it to a product of geometric series. Is it $\lvert \alpha \rvert < 1$ or $\alpha < 1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty\left((-1)^{m-n+1}\cdot\beta^n\cdot\alpha^m\right)=-\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-\beta)^n\right)\left(\sum_{m=0}^\infty(-\alpha)^m\right).$$

Now this is just a product of convergent (as $\lvert\alpha\rvert,\lvert\beta\rvert<1$) geometric series, and so

$$S=-\left(\frac{1}{1+\beta}-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{1+\alpha}\right)=\frac{\beta}{(1+\alpha)(1+\beta)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The right sum is just $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-a)^m=1/(1-a)$
then you have the outer sum times this result.

Comment: I think you’re missing a backslash somewhere